# Know, ahead of time, how long a speechSynthesis utterance will be?

Tags: javascript, text-to-speech

I have a page on which I want to show the amount of time a TTS utterance will take. The only way I've found so far is to speak the text first, then use that information later. This isn't great for long text since you have to wait the full period.

Does anybody know of any formula, services or server-side tools (not for generating tts audio) that can calculate the spoken duration of a peice of text before it's spoken?

Here's my basic example showing the minimum use case.

```js
function HHMMSS(s) {
  let date = new Date(1970, 0, 1);
  date.setSeconds(s);
  result = (date.toTimeString().replace(/.*(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}).*/, "$1"));
  return result.replace(/^00:/, "");
}

async function calc_duration(text) {
  const utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
  utterance.text = text;
  utterance.rate = 1;
  utterance.volume = 0;
  window.speechSynthesis.speak(utterance);
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    utterance.addEventListener('end', (e) => {
      resolve(e.elapsedTime);
    });
  });
}

const range = document.querySelector('input[type="range"]');
const word = document.querySelector('output');
const time = document.querySelector('p');
const text = document.querySelector('textarea').value;
const words = text.split(/\s+/).length;
calc_duration(text).then(total => {
  range.min = 1;
  range.max = text.length;
  const utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
  utterance.addEventListener('boundary', (e) => {
    word.textContent = text.slice(e.charIndex, e.charIndex + e.charLength);
    time.textContent = `${HHMMSS(e.elapsedTime)} / ${HHMMSS(total)} (${words} words)`;
    range.value = e.charIndex;
  });
  utterance.addEventListener('end', () => {
    range.value = range.max
  });
  utterance.text = text;
  utterance.rate = 1;
  utterance.volume = 1;
  // utterance.voice = speechSynthesis.getVoices()[0];
  window.speechSynthesis.speak(utterance);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <textarea rows="20" cols="80">
The rate property of the SpeechSynthesisUtterance interface gets and sets the speed at which the utterance will be spoken at.
If unset, a default value of 1 will be used.
A float representing the rate value. It can range between 0.1 (lowest) and 10 (highest), with 1 being the default rate for the current platform or voice, which should correspond to a normal speaking rate. Other values act as a percentage relative to this, so for example 2 is twice as fast, 0.5 is half as fast, etc.
</textarea><br />
  <input type="range" style="width:25vw"><output></output>
  <p></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: There is no universal formula as the result depends on the "speaker"—the speech synthesis engine and input parameters. Perhaps you can collect stats and derive your formula to give you an estimation of the duration based on the number of words and parameters of the speech synthesis.

Comment: Could max out the rate, play it, and calculate the duration from that. MDN says it only goes up to 10x rate so it's not the best alternative.